# cURL: Invalid JSON when sending stdin as data

Tags: json, bash, curl

I can control a Philips Hue light with the following command via cURL:

```
curl -X PUT --data '{"on":true}' "http://<bridgeip>/api/<key>/lights/7/state";
```

I am generating the payload with a function, so I wanted to pipe it to cURL (to take its input from stdin):

```
onString='{"on":true}';
echo "$onString" | curl -X PUT --data - "http://<bridgeip>/api/<key>/lights/7/state";
```

but this throws an error: "body contains invalid json"

What I don't get is that this works:

```
onString='{"on":true}';
curl -X PUT --data "$onString" "http://<bridgeip>/api/<key>/lights/7/state";
```

Can anyone explain please?

(Incidentally, when I pipe the output of my function to `cat` the resultant string is as expected and when copied and pasted into jsonlint checks out as valid JSON.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--data -`  doesn't fetch data from stdin, it just sends a literal `-` ,

to actually fetch data from stdin, use `--data @-`

(come to think of it, `--data-binary @-`  is probably a better idea, i think it makes a difference with newlines when running on windows, but im not 100% sure)

Comment: That works. Thank you. It's confusing that the cURL man says: "If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin."

Comment: I wanted to delete my question -even though you have been helpful- but some people have decided to start downvoting so I guess I'll just have to deal with it!

Comment: @Lorccan any idea why you get downvotes? the only thing i'm conflicted on is "should this question be on stackoverflow.com or is it a superuser.com question?", but that doesn't warrant a downvote, at best it warrants a close/transfer vote

Comment: I can't see any reason, but then I asked the question!  Not sure I get the distinction between stack overflow and superuser, so perhaps you're right.